# Sharepoint caml update batch: how pass null value

Tags: sharepoint, batch-file, null, updates, caml

When I need to update some values in the SharePoint list I create the caml-batch like this:

```
<Batch ListVersion="1" OnError="Continue">
<Method Cmd="Update" ID="1">
    <Field Name="ID">123</Field>
    <Field Name="MyField">my value</Field>
</Method></Batch>
```

How can I pass the null-value to such a batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass an empty value.

```
<Field Name="MyField"></Field>
```